# How to display different templates, like error pages, in the same Angular X app

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Is in Angular 8 way to change templates in the same application?

For example, app includes container component built with header, sidebar, footer. Then the content is always displayed inside the container.

What if I would like to display [an error page](https://httperrorpages.github.io/HttpErrorPages/HTTP403.html), which includes buttons with redirection to other pages. I don't want to load that page inside the container, but as a separate page/template, with different body/html styles etc.

I know this could be done with `innerHTML`, which is bad idea.
I've implemented so far something which I'm not happy with using `TemplateRef`, because it works only partially. Styles of body/html tags of error page are not reflected, unless are not encapsulated - which is another bad idea.

In **app.component** I change the template depending on condition - this is also not working well, because condition is the error server response, which is asynchronous.

```
<app-container *ngIf="!condition"></app-container>
<div *ngIf="condition">
  <app-container *ngTemplateOutlet="wrapper.errorTemplate"></app-container>
  <app-error #wrapper></app-error>
</div>
```

In **error.component** I have:

```
@ViewChild('errorTemplate', { static: true }) errorTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

What I've done above could be probably also achieved by implementation of conditional display **container.component** children without using `TemplateRef`

What is the best practice to get this done?

Answer (score 1):

You can go for a multi layer routing:

root.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

root.routing.ts

```
export const RootRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'error', loadChildren: 'path/to/error/module#ErrorModule',
  { path: '', loadChildren: 'path/to/app/module#AppModule' },
  { path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'error/404' },
];
```

This means that you have to bootstrap your `RootModule` and add the `RootComponent` to the bootstrap array, and change the tag in your `index.html` to something like `<app-root></app-root>`.

From there you load the `AppModule`, if the path in the url does not match 'error'.

---

Another way could be to use a service to hide header, sidebar and footer, whenever an error page is loaded.

Simple example:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ContainerService {
  readonly isErrorPage$ = this.router.events.pipe(
    filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
    map((event: NavigationEnd) => event.urlAfterRedirects.startsWith('/error')),
    shareReplay(1)
  );

  constructor(private router: Router) {}
}
```

Which you can use in your `AppContainer`:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class ContainerComponent {
  readonly showContainerElements$ = this.cs.isErrorPage$.pipe(
    map((isErrorPage) => !isErrorPage)
  );

  constructor(private cs: ContainerService) {}
}
```

and in the template:

```
<app-container-header *ngIf="showContainerElements$ | async"></app-container-header>
<app-container-sidebar *ngIf="showContainerElements$ | async"></app-container-sidebar>
<app-container-footer *ngIf="showContainerElements$ | async"></app-container-footer>
```

Comment: Thanks @Pierre for your input. I've failed to implement the first solution, which is probably the only one should be. I've got some modules errors, so I've switched to your second solution which is just a workaround, however my current  app configuration is temporary, so the problem will not exist when move to desired one. Anyway will try to apply multi-level routing aside, just to practice this conception.

Comment: @mpro It's difficult to give a working example for your situation, without knowing the entire structure of your application. What kind of errors did you get?